# Extending a projection $S\setminus L\to \Bbb{P}^1$ to the whole cubic surface $S$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $S\subset\Bbb{P}^3_\Bbb{C}$ be a nonsingular cubic algebraic surface containing a line $L$. We define the projection $\varphi:S\setminus L\to \Bbb{P}^1$ away from $L$ in the following manner. Take $M=\Bbb{P}^1\subset\Bbb{P}^3$ a line disjoint from $L$. For $P\in S\setminus L$, define $\varphi(P)$ as the only point in the intersection of $M$ and the plane $\Pi$ containing $P$ and $L$.

In Miles Reid's [chapters on algebraic surfaces](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9602006.pdf) (page $9$), there's the following reasoning for extending the projection $\varphi$ to the whole surface $S$ (I paraphrase):

> Let $H=L+F$ be a hyperplane section containing $L$. Computing the intersection numbers we get $HL=1$, $FL=FH=2$, so $H^2=3$ and $F^2=0$. Since the $F$ are effective and disctinct, they must be disjoint, so $\varphi$ is well-defined along $L$ as well".

I do understand the computations of the intersection numbers and also the fact that $F\geq 0$ and $F^2=0$ implies that the linear system $|F|$ is base-point free, which means there is a morphism $S\to\Bbb{P}^n$, where $n=\dim|F|$ (dimension as a projective space).

I still wasn't able to explain 1) why $n=1$ and 2) why the new morphism $S\to\Bbb{P}^1$ given by $|F|$ actually *extends* $\varphi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the short exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_S(-L) \to \mathcal{O}_S \to \mathcal{O}_L \to 0.
$$
Twisting it by $H$ one gets
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}_S(F) \to \mathcal{O}_S(H) \to \mathcal{O}_L(1) \to 0.
$$
The global sections are 4-dimensional for the middle term, 2-dimensional for the right term, and the restriction morphism is surjective, hence the global sections of  $\mathcal{O}_S(F)$ are 2-dimensional.

Moreover, this proves that the linear subsystem in $|H|$ consisting of divisors containing $L$ (which defines the morphism $\varphi$ away from $L$) coincides with the linear system $|F| + L$. If you recall the definition of a morphism given by a linear system you will see that the morphisms of $S \setminus L$ given by these two linear systems coincide.

Comment: How did you know the dimension of $H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(H))$ is $4$?

Comment: If $L=V(\ell_1,\ell_2)$, where $\ell_1,\ell_2$ are linear forms, then $\varphi=(\ell_1:\ell_2)=\left(1:\frac{\ell_2}{\ell_1}\right)$. Since $F\geq 0$, then $1\in\mathcal{L}(F)$. So I should be able to prove that $\frac{\ell_2}{\ell_1}\in\mathcal{L}(F)$, i.e.  $\text{div}\left(\frac{\ell_2}{\ell_1}\right)+F\geq 0$, right?

Comment: To compute global sections of $\mathcal{O}_S(H)$ you can twist the resolution of $\mathcal{O}_S$ on $\mathbb{P}^3$. I wouldn't write $(\ell_1 : \ell_2) = (1 : \ell_2/\ell_1)$. Instead, it makes sense to note that since $L \subset S$ the cubic equation of $S$ can be written in the form $\ell_1 q_1 + \ell_2 q_2$, then on $S$ one has $(\ell_1 : \ell_2) = (q_2 : -q_1)$, so the morphism $\varphi$ can be given by $(q_2 : - q_1)$. Finally, note that $q_1$ and $q_2$ form the basis of $|F|$.

Comment: Sasha, but $q_1,q_2$ are polynomials, not rational functions, so how do they belong to $|F|$? And I still can't see how do we associate $q_1,q_2$ to $F$.

Comment: The linear system $|F|$ consists of effective divisors linearly equivalent to $H - L$. Both $q_1 = 0$ and $q_2 = 0$ are such divisors.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you!